# File Utils plugin - command 'fileutils.duplicateFile' not found

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using FIle Utils plugin (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sleistner.vscode-fileutils) for Visual Studio Code.

When I try to >File Duplicate, Visual Code says "command 'fileutils.duplicateFile' not found".

I uninstall the plugin then re-install it, does not work.

I closed Visual Code, restarted mac, clear Visual Clear Editor History.

I still can not use the plugin to duplicate file or rename file.

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: Actually, a github issue recommended to update VSCode, which is what I did and it fixed it. I had to download a new version from the website though, since "Check for updates" was showing that there are no new updates.

Answer (score 0):

Update VSCode to the latest version will fix the issue. I posted in File Utils github issue

Answer (score 0):

For me following worked

- Uninstall extension
- Close VSCode
- Open VSCode and install extension

Should start working